# How to get Users email address on the layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am in need of the users email address in my layout view for my dashboard. I have tried a couple of things and they do not seem to work. Without a controller i cannot use ViewBag. I have an area where i can get users information but it does not have the or is not retrieving the email. Here is what that code looks like.

```
    public static string GetUserInfo(string value)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        string ReturnVal = string.Empty;

        switch (value)
        {
            case "email":
                ReturnVal = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                break;
            case "name":
                ReturnVal = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                break;
            case "userid":
                ReturnVal = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                break;
            case "roleid":
                ReturnVal = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                break;
            default:
                ReturnVal = "";
                break;
        }

        return ReturnVal;

    }
```

I am using entity framework and the above code was taken from a project that did not. I get all but the email from it. It returns null. Is there something i need to put in the IdentityModel with claims for it to show up?

I have also tried to use this in the layout view. But it does not let the view load, and says there is no connection to the database. However when i comment it out the page loads with no problem.

```
 @{ string email = Membership.GetUser().Email; }
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:
I added this to my IdentityModels

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("EmailAddress", this.Email.ToString()));
```

Which now gives me the email, However in my GetUserInfo it is null. It shows up if you hover over Claims as

```
{Email: this@email.com}
```

If You hover over Email in the String

```
 ReturnVal = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

You get

```
 http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
```

So i am getting the email but not the way ClaimsPrincipal has it.. 
Therefore i am unable to retrieve it..

Any Suggestions on getting this into claims the right way??

UPDATE:
On a whim i decided to change the string like this:

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", this.Email.ToString()));
```

I found this info -- NoWhere! But it works! I now get the email address in the form i need it in.

Comment: are you sure the casting of CurrentPrincipal to ClaimsIdentity is not losing that email address, IFF that email address actually exists on the CurrentPrincipal ?

Comment: The email exists in the database. It just does not show up there. I am thinking i need to add the claim to IdentityModel. I just cannot find anything that shows how to properly do that. Email would not be in there out of the box as it is part of the account but not mart of identity.. If i am reading things correctly..

Comment: Use a debugger to see what values you have and where it is getting lost.

Comment: Claims Identity only comes back with 5 the email is not there. only rolename, username, nameIdentifier, the other 2 are schemas. I think i need to add email to claims in IdentityModels but like i said i am having a hard time finding how to implement it..